# I would like to display only the teaser view of nodes

Tags: views, nodes, entities

I hope someone can help me. Here's my issue:

I'd like to create a content type - let's call it News Story.

Amongst its other attributes, this content type will have a taxonomy field.

I would like to be able to create a number of views around my site to display a subset of the News Story content, based on its taxonomy value.

However, I do not want the News Story to generate a standalone node/page - I only want the news stories to appear in views of news stories.

Have you done this before? How did you do it?

I'd be really grateful for your help.

Thanks

Comment: you should take a look at the rabbithole module. with it you can redirect detail pages to any url you like

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use the Rules module.
Add a new rule and set this:

Condition:

- Node is of type: News Story
- Custom PHP: check display_id == full
- User rôle: not admin/editor (so you can still view/edit if you're not anonymous)

Action:

- Redirect to the page you want (404 or your news list for example)

Answer (score 0):

In fact in the end I used the Rabbit Hole module:

https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole

...as suggested by Alex. It pretty much exactly met my use case.

> Rabbit Hole is a module that adds the ability to control what should happen when an entity is being viewed at its own page.
>
> Perhaps you have a content type that never should be displayed on its own page, like an image content type that's displayed in a carousel. Rabbit Hole can prevent this node from being accessible on its own page, through node/xxx.

@todo description of how I used it.

Comment: Hello. Please remove "thank you" from your answer, or it might be deleted as not an answer. At the same time, could you add a few words of description how rabbit hole meets your use case? I mean, even if it meets it exactly, you can post an excerpt from module's project page.